# django-tenant-schemas & avatars

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant, avatar

Multi tenant django 1.8 setup (using django-tenants schemas)

requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.8.16
django-allauth==0.27.0
django-tenant-schemas==1.6.4
django-avatar==3.1.0
...
```

Keeping the tenants as much as possible isolated, so kept only these APPs shared (note that allauth is not here, each tenant has its own auth_user table):

```
SHARED_APPS = (
    'tenant_schemas',  # mandatory
    'customers', 
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
)
```

Serving avatars (from /media URL) is posing an issue now since the avatar URL is unaware of the tenants.
Avatars are served from

```
/media/avatars/<user ID>/userx-pic.jpg
```

but to avoid clashes it should take the tenants into account. Target is to have:

```
/media/avatars/<tenant>/<user ID>/userx-pic.jpg
```

How can this be configured?
I am thinking of using RedirectView (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview)

... but the avatars also need to be stored in the correct location.
So the question is twofold:

1. How to get the avatars in the correct -tenant aware- location?
2. How to serve them correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to save your media files to specific tenant folder by specifying [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) on your file field and serve it as usual. For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import connection

def get_tenant_specific_upload_folder(instance, filename):
    upload_folder = 'avatars/{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(
        connection.tenant,
        instance.user.pk,
        filename
    )
    return upload_folder

class Avatar(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_tenant_specific_upload_folder)
```

p.s. for limiting avatar access only for owners take a look at [this article](https://wellfire.co/learn/nginx-django-x-accel-redirects/)

Comment: Interesting answer. But not a complete solution since I do not define my own avatar, but use django-tenant. But you made me think and I found this issue: https://github.com/grantmcconnaughey/django-avatar/issues/10  If we can get access to 'request' within this AVATAR_PATH_HANDLER, then the problem is solved ;)

Comment: @Davy well, [Avatar model](https://github.com/grantmcconnaughey/django-avatar/blob/master/avatar/models.py) have user field, so you still can get user with `instance.user` within AVATAR_PATH_HANDLER as well as tenant with `connection.tenant`, is this what you want?

Comment: Indeed, getting access to connection.tenant would solve the issue. How to get access from my avatar path handeler? def my_avatar_path_handler(instance=None, filename=None, size=None, ext=None)

Comment: @Davy just import connection with `from django.db import connection` and use `connection.schema_name` (not `connection.tenant` as i wrote in the answer; sorry, it's my mistake, i will correct it), you can read about it in docs [here](http://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html?highlight=current#creating-a-tenant)

Comment: @Davy probably you can use any of `connection.schema_name` or `connection.tenant`, try it plz

Comment: @Davy also you can look at available django-tenant-schemas database connection attributes and methods [here](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas/blob/master/tenant_schemas/postgresql_backend/base.py) in `DatabaseWrapper`

Comment: Great solution. Thx a lot. This now works like a breeze.     def my_avatar_path_handler(instance=None, filename=None, size=None, ext=None):
    path = avatar_path_handler(instance, filename, size, ext)
    parts = path.split('/')
    parts.insert(1, connection.schema_name)
    new_path = '/'.join(parts)
    return new_path

Comment: @Davy glad to help xD